# Centering Table Inside FieldSet

Tags: html, css

I am looking for the best solution on how to center my `table` inside a `fieldset`. I will post my code below:

```
<fieldset class="File">
        <legend class="sub">
            <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" Text="Text Goes Here"></asp:Label></legend>
            <asp:Table ID="Table3" runat="server" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="0">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                    <h3 class="title">Text Goes Here</h3>
                     <div id="newID" >
                     </div>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <h3 class="title">
                            <asp:Label ID="newerID" runat="server" Text="Test"></asp:Label></h3>
                        <div id="newestID" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
                        </div>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
    </fieldset>
```

I have charts inside of each `tablecell` and I am trying to center the two charts in the center of the `fieldset` which is wrapping the whole table....

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with the rendered html/css?

Comment: Post your style also